# how to get the size after apply constraints by code

Tags: swift

I am actually adding constraints to view

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var containerHeigthconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    let myView : UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerHeigthconstraint.constant = containerView.frame.width * 9 / 16 + 40
        containerView.backgroundColor = .green

        setupLayout()



    }

    func setupLayout(){
        containerView.addSubview(myView)
        myView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
        myView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor,constant: -10).isActive = true
        myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
        myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor,constant: -10).isActive = true
        print(myView.frame)
    }

}
```

This is the output and as you can see, myView has width and height, but when I print myView.frame
I get (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), I'd like to know how can i get the real size after apply constraints.

[image: output in simulator]

Comment: I think `myView.layoutIfNeeded()` will do the trick. Use it before printing the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints are not applied immediately. When you activate a new constraint, it will mark the view as needing an update, but will not actually perform the update until a future UI cycle.

So you have two options. You can call `layoutIfNeeded()` after activating the constraints to force them to be applied right away, or you can move your print statement to a later method (such as `viewDidAppear()`) which will trigger after the updates made by `viewDidLoad()` have completed. Which option you need will depend on what you're wanting to do with the frame.